# Should all cohomology theories have a smooth proper base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cohomology, motives

Let $H$ be a cohomology theory with respect to some Grothendieck topology (e.g. Zariski, analytic, etale, fppf, Nisnevich, etc.)

Does H satisfy smooth proper base?

If yes, does this mean that "motives" (should?) satisfy smooth proper base change?

I'm mostly interested in the case that the sheaves involved have no torsion.

Comment: The answer is definitely "no" for the first part of your question, and it is rather difficult to formulate a conjecture on motives that would be related to its second part.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko The cohomology theories I am familiar with (eg etale cohomology) satisfy smooth proper base change if one avoids certain characteristics. Does smooth proper base change fail for Nisnevich or some other Grothendieck topology?

Comment: Proper base change is only true for etale cohomology with (locally?) CONSTANT coefficients. This is a very specific property!

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Thank you for your comment. I see now that I was being too vague in my question (and comment).  My apologies. Let me ask a slightly more precise question: Does smooth proper base change with finite abelian coefficients fail "for obvious reasons" for other cohomology theories like Nisnevich, h-topology, fppf, etc?

Comment: For h-topology you will just get the corresponding etale cohomology.:) For other topologies one has to compute...